Why isn't my React Native screen updating when the value returned from my custom hook changes?
I have a React Native app which calls an API to get a list of items, and then displays them on one of the screens; that screen also has a toolbar which causes the list to be filtered.  However, the filtered list isn't updating on screen, and I'm not sure why.
So, my hook code is:
const useItems = () => {
  const [allItems, setAllItems] = React.useState(null);
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = React.useState(null);
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Get all items from the API
    const getAllItems = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await getItems(); // This calls the API and returns an array of items
        setAllItems(res);
      } catch {
        console.log('Unable to retrieve items');
      }
    };

    getAllItems();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!allItems) return;

    // Apply filter, if it exists
    let filteredList = [...allItems];
    if (filter !== '') {
      filteredList = allItems.filter(i=> i.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()));
    }

    setFilteredItems([...filteredList]);
  }, [allItems, filter]);

  return {filteredItems, setFilter};
};

export default useItems;

The screen which shows this list is:
const ItemListScreen = () => {
  const {filteredItems} = useItems();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(filteredItems?.length);
  }, [filteredItems]);

  return <Filter/>;
};

export default ItemListScreen;

The Filter is:
const Filter = () => {

  const {setFilter} = useItems();

  const handleChangeText = (e: string) => {
    setFilter(e);
  };

  return <Input placeholder="Filter" onChangeText={handleChangeText} />
};

export default Filter;

So, on first loading the ItemListScreen screen, the useEffect hook in useItems should be triggered, and allItems should be retrieved from the API.  This triggers the other useEffect hook within the useItems hook, and this will check the filter, see that it's null, and just copy all of allItems to filteredItems.  At this point, the console shows the length of filtered items (which is 100, as there are 100 items).
Then the user can type something into the Filter input box; this will trigger the second useEffect in useItems - this time it takes the list of all items, and checks which ones have a name which includes the filter term (so if the user has typed 'test', then only items which have 'test' in their name will be passed through the filter).  Then this shorter list of items is copied to filteredItems.  This bit appears to work fine.
However, within ItemListScreen, the useEffect doesn't get triggered, even though filteredItems has changed.
What am I doing wrong here?

You are using useItems on two separate components, that's why they "don't see" each other.  You need to create a context to achieve what you want to do (if you want to avoid prop drilling from a parent component).

Ok... so is it using 2 different instances of the hook or something?

Exactly! Personally I would solve it with a state manager like zustand, see example

For this to work across different components you need to either use a state manager as mentioned above, or you can create a context using react useContext.

The solution is to use context or state management tool.
Better is to use React built it context API.

Thank you!  I didn't realise that hooks could be instantiated more than once, but it makes sense now (and actually might be useful in a couple of other places...).  Thanks!
